# Iterating through loop of objects and changing property js

Tags: javascript

I have and array of objects:

```
words = [{id: 1, selected: true}, {}, {},...]
```

I need to unselect all words, I will have up to 10k words, so I wonder what will be faster:

```
words.filter(x => x.selected).forEach(function(w){
    w.selected = false
})
```

or just:

```
words.forEach(function(w){
    w.selected = false
})
```

ps: I use onefrontend framework which doesn't matter in this case, so I don't need to change my array - it changes automatically if I change item.

pps: 
Why are you dowvoting or closing?
I have got 2 different comments on my question and they say opposite thing.

Comment: Well you've got to iterate through the whole list one way or the other. It probably makes little practical difference; do whichever looks better to you.

Comment: The one that does only 1 iteration will "objectively" be faster.  I put that in quotes because the given operations are so simple.  You should profile your code for both options.  In essence though, you're asking should I iterate 100 items or ~120 items.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following code snippet, you will see that running it will give you different results as to which function is faster each time. It is really up to you as neither one over the other will provide much functional difference in speed.

```html
<script>
var words = [{id: 1, selected: true}, {id: 2, selected: true}, {id: 3, selected: true}, {id: 4, selected: true}, {id: 5, selected: true}, {id: 6, selected: true}, {id: 7, selected: true}, {id: 8, selected: true}, {id: 9, selected: true}, {id: 10, selected: true}];
console.time('function1');
function1();
console.timeEnd('function1');
console.time('function2');
function2();
console.timeEnd('function2');
function function1(){
words.filter(x => x.selected).forEach(function(w){
    w.selected = false;
});
}
function function2(){
words.forEach(function(w){
    w.selected = false;
});
}
</script>
```